# inflection point of degree 3 polynomial

Tags: calculus

I want to show that the inflection point of a degree 3 polynomial $f(x)$ is at
$$
x = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3},
$$
if $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3) = 0$. I was trying to show that the sign of $f''(x)$ changes at $x$, but how can I show this for an arbitrary polynomial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. That means the sign of $f''(x)$ changes when $6ax+2b=0$, so when $x=\frac{-b}{3a}$.

Since the sum of the roots of $f$ equals $\frac{-b}{a}$, we have that $x=\frac{-b}{3a}=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}$.

Comment: why is the sum $x_1+x_2+x_3$ equal to $-b/a$?

Comment: @somebody Because $$\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) &=&ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d \\
&=&a(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})(x-x_{3}) \\
&=&ax^{3}-a\left( x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}\right)
x^{2}+a(x_{1}x_{2}+x_{1}x_{3}+x_{2}x_{3})x-ax_{1}x_{2}x_{3}\text{,} \\
&\Rightarrow &-a\left( x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}\right) =b
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: See the example with the cubic function here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Example

Answer (score 2):

You know that $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, so $f''(x)=6ax+2b=0$ implies that $x=$ $___$. What do you know about the relationship between the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ and the roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$?